# Why NIntegrate does not give correct answer for smaller values of input

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

(*In the following code NIntegration does not give correct result when
         input falls below 0.9.*)

```
mu22[k_] := NIntegrate[
  z  *1/Sqrt[
  2 π] (3/(3 + z*k))^(3/2) Exp[(-3 z^2)/(
  2 (3 + k*z))]*(Erf[z/Sqrt[2 (1 + (k*z)/3)]] + 
  Exp[18/k^2]*Erf[-(z + 6/k)/Sqrt[2 (1 + (k*z)/3)]]), 
 {z, -3/k, ∞}];
```

Fails:

```
mu22[.5]
```

> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge...near {z} = {1.39454}....

```
(* Out: 8.433254185*10^14 *)
```

Succeeds:

```
mu22[.9]
(* Out: 0.5493575446 *)
```

Comment: its (mathematically) ok as `z->-3/k` because `Erf[Infinity]` is 1.  This is part of the difficulty numerically integrating the thing though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral over negative `z` has a large positive value and the integral over the positive domain has a large nearly equal negative value. 
I managed to get high precision results by breaking the integral into two parts:

```
mu22[k_] :=
 NIntegrate[
   z*1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (3/(3 + z*k))^(3/2) Exp[(-3 z^2)/(2 (3 + k*z))]*
    (Erf[z/Sqrt[2 (1 + (k*z)/3)]] + 
      Exp[18/k^2]*Erf[-(z + 6/k)/Sqrt[2 (1 + (k*z)/3)]]),
   {z, -3/k, 0}, WorkingPrecision -> 50] +
  NIntegrate[
   z*1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (3/(3 + z*k))^(3/2) Exp[(-3 z^2)/(2 (3 + k*z))]*
    (Erf[z/Sqrt[2 (1 + (k*z)/3)]] + 
      Exp[18/k^2]*Erf[-(z + 6/k)/Sqrt[2 (1 + (k*z)/3)]]),
   {z, 0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
Table[mu22[i/10], {i, 1, 9}]
```

> {err, err, err, 0.6, 0.55939805, 0.557353,0.55498491455072,0.55231,0.54935762525154}

I'm not convinced this is a correct result, but it seems reasonable.  The "exact" .6 is interesting..

Comment: It is correct for 5/10 to 9/10. For 0.1, it should be 0.56399, and in fact for k=0 it is 0.56419. Thanks .

Comment: It "seems" the `Exp[18/k^2]*Erf.. ` term integrates to zero.  No luck trying to show that in a convincing way however.

Comment: Is it possible to increase the working precision? I guess that should resolve the issue upto some extent.

Comment: playing with working precision is how I arrived at "It seems". I guess it depends on your application and how confident you need to be if you want to believe that kind of numeric result.

Comment: The "exact" 0.6 is actually ``0.5610991269147620893`0.9908795242543437``, which suggests the input has reached the boundary of catastrophic precision loss.

Comment: @MichaelE2  : These numbers are computed and published for {k,{0, 2.5, 0.1}}. Tallying, the value 0.5611 seems correct for k=0.4. How to regain from the precision loss?

Comment: It might be fruitful to post this on math.stackexchange.com. I don't see any way to analytically simplify this but maybe someone there will.  Note the second `Erf` is essentially `-1` over the entire domain, but its not obvious if that is a valid simplification or not.

Answer (score 2):

As @george2079 says, the second term in the parenthesis integrates to zero:

```
Assuming[k > 0, 
  Integrate[z*1/Sqrt[2π] (3/(3 + z*k))^(3/2) Exp[(-3 z^2)/(2 (3 + k*z))]*
  (Exp[18/k^2]*Erf[-(z + 6/k)/Sqrt[2 (1 + (k*z)/3)]]), {z, -3/k, ∞}]]
```

> 0

So we only need to integrate the first term in the parenthesis, which is easy:

```
mu22[k_] := NIntegrate[z*1/Sqrt[2π] (3/(3 + z*k))^(3/2) Exp[(-3 z^2)/(2 (3 + k*z))]*
            (Erf[z/Sqrt[2 (1 + (k*z)/3)]]), {z, -3/k, ∞}]

Table[mu22[k], {k, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

> {0.563994, 0.563409, 0.562441, 0.561099, 0.559398, 0.557354, 0.554985, 0.552312, 0.549358, 0.546144}

Comment: (+1) Please comment on the methodological similarity with the approach your took [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198939/34008).

Comment: @AntonAntonov I strongly believe that before we explore numerical options (`WorkingPrecision`, `Method`, etc.) we must exhaust analytic transformations. In other words, instead of using a faster car on the exact route proposed by the OP, first check if we can find a shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of an application of the approaches listed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198935/34008) of ["NIntegrate doesn't evaluate"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198926/34008).

We increase the working precision, specify modest precision goal (that corresponds to the machine precision computation), and we specify large enough `MinRecursion`.

```
Clear[mu22]
mu22[k_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  NIntegrate[z*(1/Sqrt[2*Pi])*(3/(3 + z*k))^(3/2)*
         Exp[(-3*z^2)/(2*(3 + k*z))]*(Erf[z/Sqrt[2*(1 + (k*z)/3)]] +               
      Exp[18/k^2]*Erf[-(z + 6/k)/Sqrt[2*(1 + (k*z)/3)]]), 
  {z, -3/k, Infinity}, 
  opts, PrecisionGoal -> 6, MinRecursion -> 4, WorkingPrecision -> 30]; 

mu22[4/10, MinRecursion -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
(* 0.56109912691473474278093871991934804555057780817151 *)

mu22[5/10]
(* 0.559398049241961146450206736125 *)

mu22[6/10]
(* 0.557353711744127129697499796898 *)

mu22[9/10]
(* 0.549357625251542853028279744451 *)
```

The comparison computation from the [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/172762/34008):

```
Table[TimeConstrained[mu22[i/10, MinRecursion -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 50], 200], {i, 1, 9}]

(* During evaluation of In[19]:= NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. *)

(* During evaluation of In[19]:= NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in z near {z} = {1.095980305962580454464980064514005730364537970159427154551846177428701345757689625003204536254789809}. NIntegrate obtained -5.055602990319483773686220288847878705656214979951156205424982827525690691913603370306862497743044896*10^25 and 9.297088667477530482343599956196447156134025802833492431136165342000934397235532650950740214993203116`100.*^27 for the integral and error estimates. *)

(* {$Aborted, $Aborted, \
-5.0556029903194837736862202888478787056562149799512*10^25, \
0.56109912691473474278093871991934804555057780817151, \
0.55939805009602787878559785757854780600727159330663, \
0.55735371174412712980920126629089419941485487591229, \
0.55498491455072038849610463055656444825264621013418, \
0.55231226836469861118654749178597901122820612288778, \
0.54935762525154285303487507916956834797845874625737} *)
```