# NIntegrate doesn't evaluate

Tags: numerical-integration

The integral

```
Integrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}]
(* 512/5355 *)
```

can be solved analytically.

Trying to apply `NIntegrate`

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}]
```

fails (although with `Method -> "PrincipalValue"`)

How can I force NIntegrate to calculate? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One should indicate the singular line (as it is described in the documentation) to calculate numerically the improper integral under consideration:

```
 NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x},Exclusions -> {t == x}]
```

> 0.0956116

Comment: Thanks, how simple...

Answer (score 20):

> > How can I force NIntegrate to calculate?

Below are listed "forcing" answers. They should apply in a wide range of situations with minimal understanding of the integrands.

### Diagnosing

First let us look at the messages given by `NIntegrate`:

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}]

(* During evaluation of In[18]:= NIntegrate::zeroregion: Integration region {{0.5,1},{1.,0.999999999999999999999999999999975153439150570957241015732418974750}} cannot be further subdivided at the specified working precision. NIntegrate assumes zero integral there and on any further indivisible regions. *)

(* During evaluation of In[18]:= NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand (t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t+x] has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.5,1},{0.999999999999999999999999999999975153439150570957241015732418974750,0.999999999999999999990527764909997233148869688962838439242343509680}}. *)

(* NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}] *)
```

The messages `NIntegrate::zeroregion` and `NIntegrate::inumri` are issued because of the application of the default singularity handler "IMT".

### Approaches

**1.** [Using `Exclusions` is one alternative](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198927/34008).

**2.** Another alternative is to prevent the singularity handler application (and increase `MaxRecursion`.)

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SingularityHandler" -> None, 
   MaxRecursion -> 120}]

(* 0.0956116 *)
```

**3.** A third alternative is to use the tuning parameters for "IMT", if you think "IMT" is beneficial. (Described in [`NIntegrate`'s advanced documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#122144792).)

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}, 
 Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
   "SingularityHandler" -> {"IMT", "TuningParameters" -> 2}}]

 (* During evaluation of In[16]:= NIntegrate::zeroregion: Integration region {{0.75,1},{1.,0.999999999999999999999999999925933445985376189112492843112221898520}} cannot be further subdivided at the specified working precision. NIntegrate assumes zero integral there and on any further indivisible regions. *)

(* 0.0956116 *)
```

**4.** [Use more sampling points per integration region](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198940/34008).

**5.** Related to 4, use higher `MinRecursion`:

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}, 
 MinRecursion -> 4]

(* 0.0956116 *)
```

**6.** [Use higher precision](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198940/34008).

**7.** [Switch the order of integration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198940/34008).

Answer (score 14):

I think the problem is that the error estimation at the singularity drives the recursive subdivision too far.  In addition to the other methods presented, here are some more.

Use a different rule (with a different error estimator):

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}, 
 Method -> "GaussKronrodRule"]
(*  0.0956116  *)
```

Switch the order of integration:

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, t, 1}]
(*  0.0956116  *)
```

Use a higher working precision:

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 16]
(*  0.09561157754126271  *)
```

---

**Addendum**

I feel `NIntegrate` should handle the OP's integral without user intervention.  The singularity should be easy to identify automatically
and easy to handle computationally. 
I think the problem is that for some unknown reason, the singularity is mishandled and that it could possibly be a bug.  Here are three "fixes" for which there is absolutely no mathematical or computational grounding that I can imagine:

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}, 
 Exclusions -> x == 100]  (* x == 100 is way outside the interation region *)
(*  0.0956116  *)

NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x}, 
 Exclusions -> t == 100]  (* ditto *)
(*  0.0956116  *)

(* Specify an ordinary point as a singularity in the `x` interval *)
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x], {x, 0, 1/2, 1}, {t, 0, x}] 
(*  0.0956116  *)
```

`NIntegrate` seems to apply [`"UnitCubeRescaling"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#46192878), which is similar to the following substitution, which I left earlier in [a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198926/nintegrate-doesnt-evaluate/198939?noredirect=1#comment515045_198939):

```
NIntegrate[
 ((t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x] /. t -> t x) * Abs@ Det@ D[{x, t x}, {{x, t}}],
 {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
(*  0.0956116  *)
```

One can partially see into the workings of `NIntegrate` using [`IntegrationMonitor`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/96663/4999):

```
ireg = NIntegrate[(t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x],
  {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, x},
  IntegrationMonitor :> (Return[#, NIntegrate] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If we compare the integrands from my substitution and from the transformation done by `NIntegrate`, we will see that they are equivalent, although symbolically they are different expressions:

```
First[ireg]["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"]
((t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x] /. t -> t x) Abs@Det@D[{x, t x}, {{x, t}}]
(*
  (t^4 x^8)/Sqrt[x - t x]
  (t^4 x^7 Abs[x])/Sqrt[x - t x]
*)
```

The only difference is that I wrapped the Jacobian determinant in `Abs[]`.  Since `0 <= x <= 1`, there's no significant difference between `x` and `Abs[x]`.  Or is there?:

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^8)/Sqrt[x - t x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

> NIntegrate::zeroregion: Integration region...cannot be further subdivided ....
>
> NIntegrate::inumri: The integrand (t^4 x^8)/Sqrt[x-t x] has evaluated to Overflow....
>
> ```
> (*  NIntegrate[(t^4 x^8)/Sqrt[x - t x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]  *)
> ```

```
NIntegrate[(t^4 x^7 Abs[x])/Sqrt[x - t x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

> ```
> (*  0.0956116  *)
> ```

In the `NIntegrate` rescaling, we get the same errors as the OP.  In the manual one, with `Abs[x]`, it works without a hitch.  It would seem that `Abs[x]` triggers a different handling of the singularity.

Again, I would repeat that I can see no justification for why the OP's code shouldn't just simply work.

Comment: Referenced this answer in mine. (Three times :)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks.  I added something about why I think the behavior of the OP's integral is strange.  I know it's been a while since you worked on `NIntegrate`, but maybe you would have an insight.

Comment: Ok, I will try to investigate/comment in more detail in the next few days. A few of preliminary comments. **1)** I had to implement and utilize "UnitCubeRescaling" for variety of reasons. Just the conceptual elegance would have been sufficient, though. Of course `NIntegrate` had non-symbolic way of handling functional boundaries. **2)** The default IMT singularity handler is fairly aggressive in flattening the singularity. If we have arbitrary precision that is kind of fine. But that extra precision hunger has to be curbed. Hence using `$MaxExtraPrecision`. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) **3)** Can you repeat your analysis using "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0 ? You might find some answers for the observed manual and automatic transformations differences... **4)** To investigate I would combine the explanations from NIntegrate's Advanced Documentation for IMT and "UnitCubeRescaling". I will very likely use the functions of the context "NIntegrateUtilities".

Answer (score 7):

You can do a linear variable substitution $y = x - t$, so that the singularity becomes more manageable:

```
Integrate[((x - y)^4 x^3)/Sqrt[y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}]
(* 512/5355 *)

NIntegrate[((x - y)^4 x^3)/Sqrt[y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}]
(* 0.0956116 *)
```

Or even eliminate the singularity completely by substituting $z = \sqrt{x-t}$:

```
Integrate[2 (x - z^2)^4 x^3, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, Sqrt[x]}]
(* 512/5355 *)

NIntegrate[2 (x - z^2)^4 x^3, {x, 0, 1}, {z, 0, Sqrt[x]}]
(* 0.0956116 *)
```

In my experience this way of proceeding is often much more fruitful than addressing the technical/methodical difficulties of `NIntegrate`.

Comment: I was just about to add your new, second method to my answer. +1

Comment: I wish someone would explain the downvote.  The IMT singularity handler works better when the singularity aligns with one of the coordinate axes.  The change of variables in the first example here does that.  I was going to add to my answer the example `NIntegrate[((t^4 x^3)/Sqrt[-t + x] /. t -> u x) Abs@ Det@ D[{x, u x}, {{x, u}}], {x, 0, 1}, {u, 0, 1}]`, which is another change of variables, `{x, t} -> {x, u x}`, that accomplishes a similar alignment and is essentially the same idea.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I downvoted the original version because it was too short of explanations, just proposing a substitute. The new version discusses the singularity elimination. (IMT "just" does singularity flattening.) Nevertheless, one of the ideas behind "big functions" like `NIntegrate` (and `NDSolve`, `NMinimize`, etc.) is that we should not think that much when using them, their frameworks should support "simple user" usage. Meaning **1)** automatic method (options) selection, or **2)** effective tweaking with minimal mathematics knowledge and/or understanding.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I actually agree with your downvote, and believe the automatic methods should be promoted instead. For those readers who have enough analysis skill to get a substitution going, what I wrote is probably rather trivial.

Comment: @Roman Unfortunately, I deal too much with problems, tasks, and situations in which people try to see without looking. That point of view usually annoys me, but I have to admit that is the goal of all mathematics and computer science productization -- less thinking required.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks for the explanation. I think it helps the site if shortcomings and potential improvements are pointed out.